# Mocking an I/O event in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

My code is listening for file changes in a folder, in class A. When a change occurs, then I trigger a function of class B, which is a field in class A.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, b):
    ...
    self.handler = b

  def run(self):
    # listen for changes in a folder using watchdog.observers.Observer
    self.observer.schedule(self.handler, self.input_directory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while not self.stopped:
                time.sleep(self.scanning_frequency)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()

        self.observer.join()

class B(FileSystemEventHandler):
  ...
  def on_any_event(self, event):
    # a change occurred and handled here.
```

Now what I want to test is that when a file is copied to this folder, then `on_any_event` should be triggered. This is how I tried to do that:

```
    def test_file_watcher(self):
        # arrange
        b = B()
        a = A(b)
        a.handler.on_any_event = MagicMock()

        shutil.copy(# copy file to the watched folder)
        p1 = Process(target=a.run)
        p1.start()

        time.sleep(folder scanning frequency + 1 second)
        a.stop() # stops watching the folder

        assert a.handler.on_any_event.called
        p1.join()
```

However this assertion turns out to be false all the time. Where am I doing wrong exactly? Also would it be possible to achieve this by also mocking B completely?

---

Edit: I think the reason could be that I am using a different process, therefore a.handler.on_any_event.called is always false. But I couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround for your test in a multiprocessing context

I agree with you that multiprocessing causes the failure of the test. I have found a workaround that can help you to do the test in a strange way, but that you can adapt for your needs.

The workaround is based on the use of *Sharing Global Variables*  in Multiprocessing by `multiprocessing.Value` (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)).

To do this I have defined 2 sharing variables and 2 functions as below:

```py
from multiprocessing import Value

shared_value = Value('i', 0)
stopped = Value('i',0)

# this function is used to substitute method on_any_event() of class B
def on_any_event_spy(event):
    shared_value.value += 1

# this is the target for Process p1
def f(a: A):
    # substitution of on_any_event method with on_any_event_spy()
    a.handler.on_any_event = on_any_event_spy
    a.run()
```

Furthermore I have to modify the `run()` and `stop()` methods of class A.

New method *stop()* of class A:

```
def stop(self):
    stopped.value = 1
```

Method *run()* of class A (change only the condition of the `while`):

```
def run(self):
    # listen for changes in a folder using watchdog.observers.Observer
    self.observer.schedule(self.handler, self.input_directory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            #while not self.stopped:   # <------ comment this instruction
            while stopped.value == 0:   # <----- add this instruction
                time.sleep(self.scanning_frequency)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()

        self.observer.join()
```

The test method becomes:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_file_watcher(self):

        # arrange
        b = B()
        a = A(b)

        shutil.copy(  # copy file to the watched folder)
        # I have changed yor target value and add args
        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(a, ))
        p1.start()

        time.sleep(a.scanning_frequency + 1)
        a.stop()  # stops watching the folder

        # the shared_value value MUST BE > 0
        self.assertGreater(shared_value.value, 0)

        p1.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### How to mock B *completely*

The previous paragraph of this answer tells that the real problem of this test is the multiprocessing, but if you want mock B *completely* as you ask in your question, try to change your `test_file_watcher()` as following:

```py
def test_file_watcher(self):
    # arrange
    #b = B()   # <---------------- ------------- comment this instruction
    b = Mock(wraps=B()) # <--------------------- add this instruction
    a = A(b)
    #a.handler.on_any_event = MagicMock() # <--- comment this instruction

    shutil.copy(# copy file to the watched folder)
    p1 = Process(target=a.run)
    p1.start()

    time.sleep(folder scanning frequency + 1 second)
    a.stop() # stops watching the folder

    #assert a.handler.on_any_event.called# <---- comment this instruction
    assert b.on_any_event.called           <---- add this instruction
    p1.join()
```

I hope that with the instruction:

```
b = Mock(wraps=B())
```

you will wrap B *completely* as you ask in your question and this can be useful for future more traditionally tests.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Although I see that the newly copied file is processed, the '.called' still returns false :(. I think it is somehow related with multiprocessing.

Comment: @JollyRoger To test if the problem is in the multiprocessing (only for study the test problem) try to define `class A(threading.Thread)` (a subclass of `Thread`) and in the test execute `a.start()` instead of `p1=Process(target=a.run)`, `p1.start()`.

Comment: So `a.start()` is a blocking function because of the `sleep` call. Therefore it just stucks at `a.start()` in this way.

Comment: @JollyRoger have edited my answer to try to execute your test by a workaround. I don't know if what I have written (and tried in my environment) could be useful for you. It is only a workaround for doing the test, but I hope that it can suggest you something useful.